# codeigniter unexpected model load

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-connection, benchmarking

I'm building an app where it contains 3 mysql database connections to 3 different databases. 
Ex.
1. Default connection => DB1 
2. conn02 => DB2 
3. conn03 => DB3

All this 3 connections use same username and password.

I called other 2 connections in model construct since it was not default. like:

```
$this->CONN2 = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);
$this->CONN3 = $this->load->database('db3', TRUE);
```

Later when i called this model in controller and while rendering the view. It was taking around 7 seconds to render the view in browser. Which was long time for a view to load in browser without any db select queries.

Then i benchmarked the model and saw the result. I came to know that model was taking time. So i disabled the database connections in the model at construct and it was loading fast. I was surprised to see the result.

Can you please tell me how to solve this issue?

Here is the image of benchmark result before and after disabling the database connections in model.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rectified the problem. If i remove 2nd parameter (TRUE) from load database. Model loads within **0.0042**. But i'm using active records so it is mandatory to pass 2nd parameter TRUE.

```
$this->CONN2 = $this->load->database('db2');
$this->CONN3 = $this->load->database('db3');
```

and i had 3 libraries auto loading "database", "session" and "custom library". When i disabled this autoload. Entire controller with model was loading within **0.0356**

Later i optimized few areas and now CI renders page quickly **<= 1sec**